# Deploy a WPF application partially

Tags: wpf, deployment

I have a WPF App and I'm using ClickOnce as deployment strategy. Everything works fine, but I have a file size issue. My application weighs about **36MB**, so every update my users have to download this file size, increasing the network bandwidth use.

But, almost 25MB don't get changed because they belong to third party components.

I was thinking about creating a custom deployment strategy:
For example, filtering only the dlls that don't change and only download the ones I want (maybe zipped) and I would update the installation folder.

I know that could sound unpractical, so are there any suggestions about how to improve the deployment size and minimize my down-time?

Comment: Nice, but I still have some third party dlls that never change and also are being downloaded everytime